# Adding a Java Strings and convert it into integer and get its sum

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I would like to need you're help for this. I need to get the total of the said equation and I'm stuck to the concatenation process which will let me add the result of the equation.

```
String eq = "15+5cdf-45+90$%#@";
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(eq);

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) >= 48 && s.charAt(i) <= 57 || s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-') {

    } else {
        s.deleteCharAt(i);
        i--;
    }

}

System.out.println(s);  

String a = new String (s);

//15+5-45+90

String y = "";
String z = "";  

for (int x = 0; x < a.length(); ++x) {

    if (a.charAt(x) == '+'){
        a = a.substring(0, x);
        y = a;
    } 

    z = y.concat(y);
}

System.out.println(z);
```

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I can't add up or get the result of the equation, Im stuck with the resulting up process.

Comment: were you  able to separate the numbers from input? you can store each of the number in an ArrayList, in the end, you iterate through the List and find the sum.

Comment: I was able to get the first number, but the second number which is 5, I cannot get that value. Also, I cannot use ArrayList since the requirement is only to use Strings.

Comment: explain this nonsense string please "15+5cdf-45+90$%#@" is it supposed to be a math statement? How do you handle special chars?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: 15+5cdf-45+90$%#@. Regarding about this, the requirement was to clean up the equation by removing the special characters, it was clean up on the code and I only need to add up the equation. So if I remove the special characters, it will look like this : 15+5-45+90

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not really familiar with StringBuilder

Comment: It's exactly the same methods, but with a different name. StringBuffer was replaced in 2004 so as a beginner it unfortunate to be learning a class which was obsolete long before you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be doing most of what you are doing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String eq = "15+5cdf-45+90$%#@";
    long sum = eval(eq);
    System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
}

private static long eval(String eq) {
    int sign = +1;
    long num = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < eq.length(); i++) {
        char ch = eq.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            num = num * 10 + ch - '0';
        } else if (ch == '-' || ch == '+') {
            sum += sign * num;
            sign = ch == '-' ? -1 : +1;
            num = 0;
        }
    }
    sum += sign * num;
    return sum;
}
```

prints

```
65
```

As you can see all you need as a parser which evaluates the expression which ignores unexpected characters.

Note: the `eval` creates no objects.

Comment: @JavaBeginner Hopefully you can see that all you need to do is go from the input to the result.  You can do with lots of steps in between, but this is actually more complex in some ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Equation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String eq = "15+5cdf-45+90$%#@";

        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer (eq);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) >= 48 && s.charAt(i) <= 57 || s.charAt(i) == '+'
                    || s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            } else {
                s.deleteCharAt(i);
                i--;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(s);

        String a = new String(s);

        // 15+5-45+90
        String term = "";
        char previousOperator = '+';
        long sum = 0;
        boolean weHavePreviousTerm = false;

        for (int x = 0; x < a.length(); x++) {
//          if we got to a new operator
            if (a.charAt(x) == '+' || a.charAt(x) == '-') {
                if (weHavePreviousTerm) {
                    int previousTermValue = Integer.parseInt(term);
                    if (previousOperator == '-') {
                        previousTermValue *= -1;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Adding " + previousTermValue);
                    sum += previousTermValue;
                }
                previousOperator = a.charAt(x);
//              reset term buffer
                term = "";
            }
            else {
                term += a.charAt(x);
                weHavePreviousTerm = true;
            }
        }

//      do the last operation
//      if the last term didn't get reset, means we still have an operation left to do
        if (term.length()  > 0) {
            int previousTermValue = Integer.parseInt(term);
            if (previousOperator == '-') {
                previousTermValue *= -1;
            }
            System.out.println("Adding " + previousTermValue);
            sum += previousTermValue;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```